# Iterate through json schema?

Tags: javascript, graph-algorithm

I have created a json schema that represent a map of island and the connection between them in this format:

```
MAP:{ sky: [ 'valley' ],
  valley: [ 'koopa' ],
  mushroom: [ 'toad' ],
  toad: [ 'koopa' ],
  koopa: [],
  twin: [ 'valley' ],
  forest: [ 'twin' ] }
```

and I have a position A and a destination B; knowing that a path always exist in the map, I need to make a function that looks for the path from A to B in the Map?

My code :

```
 Graph.prototype.getHimHome = function (position, destination, n){
      const arr = this.adjList;
      let isHome = false;
      let path = [destination];

        while( !isHome &&  n>0) {

            for( el in arr) { // looping through the json schemma
                      arr[el].forEach( element => {
                          if(element === path[path.length - 1])//this means we're on the path;
                          {
                            path.push(el);
                          } else {
                            path.push(el);
                          }
                      })
                } ;


            if(path[path.length - 1] === position){
              isHome = true;
            }
            n--;
          }

      console.log(path);

      }
```

Comment: It would help if you say what is the problem with the function you provided. What is it doing or not doing as you expected? Have you tried using a debugger and stepping through the code?

Comment: Your schema strikes me as a bit strange; there is only one destination for a given key, yet it's in an array which implies that there may be more than one destination. Is that accurate? If there is only one destination per key, why are you using arrays? As it stands, there's no real graph algorithm here and there are no route choices to be made, it's just a matter of keying into the array in a loop until you're at your destination (or not). Please clarify and provide a working [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Also as a hint, I would first make a tree structure from the JSON data, where each node stores a locations name, and a list of references to the nodes that can reach it. Then start at the destination node (B) and following the links back until you reach the starting point (A) (or not if there is no path).

Comment: the above Json schema is a tree like result, if you follow it carefully. The problem is, I couldn't produce a code that will get from A to B. :/

Comment: @ggorlen Koopa can be reached from Valley and Toad so his his structure is an inverted tree.

Comment: What I am suggesting is build the inverted tree and then work backwards B to A, to easily find the route. You can build the tree and leave it place to be used over and over rather than building it on every occasion you need a route.

Comment: @bcperth That being the case, why are the parents in an array? Each tree node can only have one parent, so there's either 1) no reason for the array or 2) the structure posted is incomplete. Either way, it's worth clarifying OP intent before posting an answer.

Comment: To clarify: the schema above, represent 'Node': [List of adjacent]

Comment: I agree the array is not the right starting point (unless he was given the array by a third party for example). The correct structure for this type of problem is a tree as I think ggorlen is pointing out. That would be incorrect if say Taod and Valley are connected, in which case a broader network structure is needed. Can you confirm what you envisage oflcad?

Comment: the above example is looking to print the path from twin ==> koopa.

Comment: thus printing koopa valley twin.

Comment: what is 'n'? can you show how you call the method?

Comment: @ShaharA n is the number of queries.